# Where is XSD file for XML found in Gdb_Items table?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase-api, geodatabase-xml, xsd

I would like to be able to deserialize the xml in Gdb_items table using .NET.

The xml in an sde geodatabase appears to be the same as the xml returned using the File GDB API.

I tried using xsd.exe to generate c# code from the xsd files in `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\XmlSchema\Geodatabase.xsd`.

While the classes are similar, e.g. `DEFeatureclass` looks a lot like the `DEFeatureclassInfo` from Gdb_Items xml, they don't match exactly.

*Does anyone know where I can get a schema definition file I can use to generate c# code that can then be used to deserialize Gdb_items xml in .NET?*